# where to set configuration options for google visulization

Tags: google-maps

I want to use google intensity map and found this, https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/intensitymap#Configuration_Options

But I cannot figure out where am I supposed to set these options (in javascript code).

I have tried `chart.height = 200` and this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find it here: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start

second parameter of `IntensityMap.draw` is for options.

```
var options = {height: 200};
chart.draw(data, options);
```

will do.